# How to set system wide PATH in ubuntu:20.04 docker image?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends sudo && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists
COPY mybin /mybin
# Add mybin to system wide path
ENV PATH=/mybin:$PATH
```

```
$ docker run --rm myimg sudo printenv
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=10adc6c192f4
HOME=/root
```

want to get

```
PATH=/mybin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

How to set mybin to system wide PATH in Dockerfile?

Answer (score -1):

You can add

```
RUN echo "PATH=/mybin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
" > /etc/environment
```

to your dockerfile

Comment: /etc/environment doesn't work.
Ref. 

``` 
$docker run --rm ubuntu:20.04 cat /etc/environment                                                                                                            
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Comment: Most paths to running Docker containers don't read `/etc/environment` or other shell dotfiles.

Comment: Try `RUN echo "export PATH=/new/path:${PATH}" >> /root/.bashrc` and see if that solves your problem as often the PATH is overwritten by .bashrc

Comment: @Jast38 Ofcourse edit .bashrc is not solution. `docker run --rm myimg sudo printenv` is not called from bash.